# Particular additive / multiplicative structures of quotient rings?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

I've come across these questions with solutions asking about the +/x tables of quotient rings, and I can't figure out where the get the solutions from.

The first example: The quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_3 [x]/(x^2+1)$ has additive structure $(a+bx+I)+(c+dx+I)=a+b+(c+d)x+I$, and multiplicative structure given by setting $x^2=2$. I cannot figure out where either of those structures come from.

The second example: The field $\mathbb{Z}[\alpha]:= \mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3+x+1)$ has multiplicative structure defined by $(a+b\alpha+c\alpha^2)(a'+b'\alpha+c'\alpha^2)=aa'+bc'+b'c+x(b(a'+c')+b'(a+c)+cc')+x^2(ca'+ac'+bb'+cc')$.

Once again I have no idea where that structure comes from. I asked my prof and the only thing she said was *"Since $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3+x+1$, then $\alpha^3=\alpha+1$"* I also have no idea where that comes from.

While I definitely want to know where these problems come from, I really just don't have an understanding in general of how to get to those. Really no explanation is given for these problems. Thank you!

Comment: There are two distinct issues here: one is understanding why one only needs a degree $n-1$ polynomial to represent an equivalence class in some polynomial ring mod a degree $n$ polynomial, and the other is understanding how addition/multiplication are defined in a generic quotient ring.

Comment: @AlexProvost I'm pretty sure I understand why they choose the polynomials they do. By I don't understand how they get from the left hand side to the right hand side of the equations, or why they set the certain values of $x/\alpha$

Comment: Note that $-1=2$ in $\Bbb Z_3$ and $-1=1$ in $\Bbb Z_2$. Letting $\alpha:=x+I$, if $x^3+x+1\in I$, then $\alpha^3+\alpha+1=0$, thus $\alpha^3=-1(\alpha+1)=\alpha+1$ over $\Bbb Z_2$.

Answer (score 2):

The additive and multiplicative structure are defined as follows in any quotient ring $R/I$:
$$(r+I)+(r'+I) = (r+r')+I$$
$$(r+I)(r'+I) = (rr') + I$$

If we look at the first example, any equivalence class in $\Bbb{Z}_3[x]/(x^2+1)$ has a unique representative of the form $(a+bx)+I$. By the generic definition above,

$$(a+bx+I)+(c+dx+I) = (a+bx+c+dx)+I = (a+c)+(b+d)x + I.$$

For multiplication,

$$(a+bx+I)(c+dx+I) = (a+bx)(c+dx)+I = ac + (ad+bc)x + bdx^2 + I,$$

and since $$x^2 +1 \in I \implies -bdx^2-bd \in I \implies I = -bdx^2-bd + I, $$

the product above may be written as $$(a+bx+I)(c+dx+I) = ac+(ad+bc)x - bd + I = (ac - bd) + (ad+bc)x + I.$$

Finally in $\Bbb{Z_3}$, we have $-1 = 2$, so we may also write $(ac + 2bd) + (ad+bc)x + I$.